# In SSL enabled magento site, Ajax Add to cart not adding product to cart until refresh the page manually

Tags: ajax, magento

We are using a template which has ajax add to cart functionality.

It was working fine for us before but after enabled SSL certificate, Ajax add to cart not adding product to the cart. It just keep on loading. Product is getting added only after i have refresh the page manually.

**Ajax add to cart code**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: can you share the link so that i can check..

Comment: https://shopindia.ezeebags.com/ Having add to cart issue with this link @Vishal Sharma.

Comment: remove the cache in var/cache folder and then check it again ... let me know the result..

Comment: Already i have removed the cache folder but still it doesn't work @Vishal Sharma

Comment: By using firebug,I have found that in prototype.js its showing the error Error: "throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead.How to fix it?Any suggestion would be appreciated..

Comment: i checked on firebug ... i am thinking that when we click on the add to cart button then Ajax data is not generating correctly bcoz links are broking ... Which magento version are you using and is this a default ajax cart or you are using some other extension... please let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58495/discussion-between-user2089987-and-vishal-sharma).